# ¿Por qué cuando se reindexa la base de datos de un programa en visual foxpro las tablas que borre aparecen con error?

Tags: visual-foxpro

tengo un programita que realice con visual foxpro y ya cuando lo termine completamente borre un par de tablas ya que los datos que iban a contener no serían de vital importancia ni serían relacionados en una cantidad inmensa como para tenerlos en una tabla separada.

Mi consulta es: sí vuelvo a indexar los datos, se me marcan dichas tablas como si estuviesen con algún error si físicamente ya no existen. Podrá ser que en algún método todavía tenga alguna línea que apunte a la tabla inexistente.

Me gustaría saber lo que piensan ya que obviamente todavía no me encuentro con un nivel alto.

Comment: "se me marcan dichas tablas como si estuviesen con algún error si físicamente" en donde? "Podrá ser que en algún método todavía tenga alguna línea que apunte a la tabla inexistente." todo es posible... O sea, con la informacion que das, es muy dificil decirte que pasa...

Comment: *...ya que los datos que iban a contener no serían de vital importancia ni serían relacionados en una cantidad inmensa como para tenerlos en una tabla separada...* Lo que falla es el enfoque que das al problema. Si el dato no tiene que estar en una tabla, no lo metas en una tabla, crea por ejemplo un pequeño archivo de preferencias o algo así. Si dejas el dato en la tabla, y la aplicación intenta buscar ese dato en dicha tabla y no lo encuentra, es evidente que tendrás un problema. La cuestión es. ¿Alguna vez se necesita ese dato? Tiene que estar disponible, del modo que sea.